# Problem with boundry for different aggregates

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I have a problem with the boundaries of aggregates. I was trying to read about aggregates, aggregate roots, and boundaries, looking for some code examples but I still struggle with it.

The app that I'm working on is an app to manage architecture projects.
Among the screens in the app there will be a screen with all details for the selected project, and one with all jobs for the selected constructor.

I have one AggregateRoot - `ArchitectureProject`.It has an `Architect`, `Stages`, etc. and it has a list of `ConstructorJobs` (as it has to be on the screen with project details). `ConstructorJob` has its name, some value, and a `Constructor`. A `Constructor` can have some `ConstructorType`. As for me, `Constructor` is another AggregateRoot. I have a problem with `ConstructorJob`. Where should I place it? What should be responsible for managing it?

I was trying to thing what cannot exist with what, and `ConstructorJob` cannot exists without `Project`, but on the other hand it has to have `Constructor` as well...
I can't imagine that `Constructor` would belong to `Project` Aggregate, as `ConstructorType` would be 4th level child to id, so searching for all constructors of that type would be painful, wouldn't be?

I would appreciate any explanation, how to handle such cases.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing an important rule which usually makes your life a lot easier:

> Rule: Reference Other Aggregates by Identity

See also Vaughn Vernon's Book [*Implementing Domain-Driven Design*](https://www.informit.com/store/implementing-domain-driven-design-9780321834577?w_ptgrevartcl=Implementing%20Domain-Driven%20Design%3A%20Aggregates_2020371), chapter 10 - Aggregates.

It is important to note that ***Aggregates*** in the sense of domain-driven design are not so much focused on if the existence of one aggregate makes sense without the other. It is more about ***transactional boundaries***. So an aggregate should create a boundary around elements that should only change together within the same transaction - to adhere to ***consistency***.

So I guess, that you will change your *Project* in different use cases you would change the *Constructor* - which I guess can be referenced in different projects.

This means you should reference other aggregates within aggregates only by id which avoids modelling huge aggregates with deep hierarchies. It also means that if your aggregates tend to grow bigger over time that you might have missed some new aggregate which you initially modelled as entity and should be an aggregate on its own.

> As for me, Constructor is another AggregateRoot. I have a problem with ConstructorJob. Where should I place it? What should be responsible for managing it?

In your case I would model it the following way:

The ***ConstructorJob*** is a ***Value Object*** which holds some data (name, etc.) and also a reference to a ***Constructor aggregate***. But this reference is not a reference in terms of **object reference** like you would do it with a child entity of an aggregate root. The constructor aggregate is referenced by an ***identifier*** (UUID, integer or whatever you are using as id type) in the ConstructorJob.

The *ConstructorJob* value object would be part of the ***Project aggregate***. The project aggregate could of course directly hold the id of the constructor aggregate but I guess in your case the value object might fit quite well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @afh for an explanation! I think it is the best possible solution, but the problem that I have with it is if I go to the `Constructor` screen, and I'd like to see all `ConstructorJobs` done by that constructor, I need to iterate over all projects to gether all `ConstructorJobs` that has that constructorId. But I think I can somehow in `Constructor` aggregate store ids/references of `Projects`, in which he/she participated.

Comment: You need to differentiate between data access for reading and data access for writing. If you need to modify something go through your aggregates to keep your data consistent by adhering to your business invariants. But if you only need to access your data for querying only you can completely bypass the domain model and create whatever separate data structures for reading only by accessing your data storage the way that best suits you. See also this answer relating to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63639838/7730554